# Blocking Calls with Reactive Spring Data Cassandra

Tags: multithreading, cassandra, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-data-cassandra

I wish to understand How Reactive Spring Data Cassandra takes care of Concurrency? Does it use the Event Loop model?

So we have Spring Webflux which uses Netty along with Reactive Spring Data Cassandra where Netty has it's own thread pool while Reactive Spring Data Cassandra has it's own pool.

In our Rest Controller one of our GET Method uses the following piece of code.

```
return personRepository.findAll()
   .map(person -> doSomeComputeIntensivetask(person))
   .filter(person -> person.getAge()>30);
```

Now what We realized is the Netty pool doesn't execute the findAll method, instead Reactive Spring Data Cassandra executes it. The thread isn't switched back to Netty Pool, instead it continues using Spring Data Cassandra Thread Pool. Does that mean Spring Data Cassandra Threads are being blocked? Would that mean, in case of too many calls the server might return 503 Service Unavailable since there won't be any Threads to execute DB Queries?

We also have a Kafka Consumer so I just wanted to understand the implication of using

```
personRepository.findByDate(date).collectList().block();
```

instead of

```
personRepository.findByDate(date).subscribe();
```

inside a Kafka Consumer.

What Concurrency model does Reactive Spring Data Cassandra use internally? Is it something Similar to CompletableFutures? Also is the Thread pool size for Reactive Spring Data Cassandra Configurable?

Comment: It's reactive, the threads are never blocked unless you block them. You shouldn't have to worry which threads are being used when using the reactive model.

Comment: Kafka Listeners are async in nature, so it's very difficult to keep DB events in sync unless they're blocking in nature. Also if we make them sequential by chaining through .then() since we weren't using publishOn() the same thread continues the flow which persisted the object due to which we observed our server returning 503 service unavailable.